# PHP7.3: How can I inherit a protected static property with the thightest possible scope without redeclaring it in the child class?

Tags: php, php-7.3

In the application I'm working on, the Model part of the MVC stack is designed to work trough singletons; each Model has a __getInstanceMethod which is

```
protected static $singleton;
public static function __getInstance(): self {
    if(self::$singleton === null) {
        self::$singleton = __CLASS__;
        self::$singleton = new self::$singleton;
    }
    return self::$singleton;
}
```

End result is, if __getInstance() is called twice on the same Model class, it returns the same exact object both times.

I tried to reduce code duplication by moving the __getInstance() method to the Model's parent class, BaseModel, by editing it like so.

```
class BaseModel {
    protected static $singleton;
    public static function __getInstance(): self {
        if (static::$singleton === null) {
            static::$singleton = static::class;
            static::$singleton = new static::$singleton();
        }
        return static::$singleton;
    }
}
class AModel extends BaseModel {
    protected static $singleton;
    /** ... */
}
class BModel extends BaseModel {
    protected static $singleton;
    /** ... */
}

AModel::__getInstance(); // AModel
BModel::__getInstance(); // BModel
```

Problem is, I need to manually add a $singleton property to each and every Model class, otherwise I'll always get returned the instance of the first Model class I called the method on.

```
class BaseModel {
    protected static $singleton;
    public static function __getInstance(): self {
        if (static::$singleton === null) {
            static::$singleton = static::$class;
            static::$singleton = new static::$singleton();
        }
        return static::$singleton;
    }
}
class AModel extends BaseModel {}
class BModel extends BaseModel {}

AModel::__getInstance(); // AModel
BModel::__getInstance(); // Still AModel
```

Is there a way I can avoid doing that?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and stop using [singletons](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) :) favor dependency injection.

Comment: @emix I'd have used Symfony, if I could've, but I'm not the one deciding it. As such, I'm stuck with a proprietary framework

Comment: Are you sure the top code works? I'm getting `BaseModel` twice for v7.2 - 7.4.2   => https://3v4l.org/N9kCi7

Comment: @Yoshi I've tried running the same exact code in my local environment, and it goes exactly as you said. Next thing I can't understand is why it works in every other instance I used it in. Could the autoloader (all Model classes are defined in their own file) have something to do with it?

Comment: @Vkfan I can't say, haven't had that problem before. Question is, is it still relevant?

Comment: @Yoshi I don't know; sure thing is, if the classes are located in a different file than the one you're using __getInstance() from, it works, and for me that's enough. Sadly, the main problem remains.

Comment: @Vkfan Well, not really, I've posted an answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could switch to an *"instance map"*, e.g.:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

class BaseModel
{
    protected static $instances = [];

    public static function __getInstance(): self
    {
        if (!isset(static::$instances[static::class])) {
            static::$instances[static::class] = new static();
        }

        return static::$instances[static::class];
    }
}

class AModel extends BaseModel
{
}

class BModel extends BaseModel
{
}

echo get_class(AModel::__getInstance()), "\n";
echo get_class(BModel::__getInstance());
```

https://3v4l.org/qG0qJ

---

and with 7.4+ it could be simplified to:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

class BaseModel
{
    private static array $instances = [];

    public static function __getInstance(): self
    {
        return static::$instances[static::class] ??= new static();
    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't even notice it was your response. Many thanks, I'll see if I can add it to the framework.